# How to use causal inference models when we don't know the structure of the graph?

Tags: inference, causality

I have recently started reading some materials in Causal Inference. Based on readings, we assume a graph that explains the relationship between treatment, outcome, and confounders. Then, they propose some methods like inverse probability weighting to compute the ATE. In many cases, we don't have access to the graph and so don't know how to find which variables to use for the adjustment formula. In this situation, how can we use IPW? should we consider all covariates?

Comment: My recommendation is to come up with the graph if you don't have it. You can use a combination of the algorithm in *Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference, 2nd Ed.,* Chapter 2 and expert input to produce the causal graph. Data can only get you so far, though: as Theorem 1.2.8 in the same book says, data can only resolve the causal graph up to the same skeleton and $v$-structures (collider locations).

Comment: Thanks for your response. In some papers, I have seen that they just used IPW without presenting the causal graph and I am wondering how reliable these methods are. If the graph is not know and a linear regression is used, I don't understand the difference between causal inference and prediction.